# Mini Cart button in Woocommerce is misalligned?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

[My site](https://touchdowner.cz/digital-products/) worked perfectly until yesterday, when after updating some plugins my Mini Cart dropdown button started to show weird and misalligned.

[image]

Before updating plugins button haved this style:

```
background-color: #070bf7;
padding: 10.5px;
border-radius: 15px;
color: #ffffff !important;
```

and currently have this CSS class:

```
a.festi-cart div.festi-cart-content
{
display: inline-block;
font-style: normal;
text-align: left;
}
```

so content into button, like number of products and price showing one bellow other, instead showing inline like button Muj Ucet from left side. So how to show button content inline, like every normal button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to thing

1) The inline alignment
  In your style.css line 1077 you have the next style

```
.sf-menu li a span {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: block;
  color: rgba(167, 167, 167, 0.9);
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

This style affect your spans inside that button. And because they have a `display: block` it breaks your button

> FIX

Add the next code:

```
.sf-menu li a span {
  display: inline !important;
}
```

2) Your button styles. I dont know what happend to them but you can just add them again.May be a class from the plugin change and lost the styles on the update.

> FIX

```
.festi-cart-content {
  background-color: #070bf7;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

> END RESULT

[image: End Result]

Hope this helps :>